# Console.log logs, but I can return in a Callback JavaScript remoting function

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

before going into details I want to say I have done my homework but not with good results, I have this javascript functions

```
function CreateInspection(){
  sforce.connection.sessionId= '{!$Api.Session_ID}';     
      try{
      var elements = document.getElementsByName('accountid');
      var id = elements[0].getAttribute('id');
      var insp = new SObjectModel.Insp({Account_del__c:id});
      insp.create(function(error,result,event) {                                        
              console.log("Error is :" + error);
              console.log("Resultado es: " + result);                         
              console.log("Evento es: " + event);                                                                
            });       
      } 
      catch(err){
      console.log("Error is :" + err);
      }                     
  }
```

And I'd like to get result[0].Id like this:

`InspectionId=CreateInspection();`

and use InspectionId's value for the next step in my development but what happens it's that it writes the value to the console but it doesn't return the value.

Obviously, I'm not as good to get this working and I'd like to see if some of you have seen something similar to this before and could help me and put me in the right way with some function code snipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can't return a value from CreateInspection because it runs asynchronously. Instead, provide a callback:

```
function CreateInspection(callback){
  sforce.connection.sessionId= '{!$Api.Session_ID}';     
      try{
      var elements = document.getElementsByName('accountid');
      var id = elements[0].getAttribute('id');
      var insp = new SObjectModel.Insp({Account_del__c:id});
      insp.create(function(error,result,event) {
              callback(error, result);
              console.log("Error is :" + error);
              console.log("Resultado es: " + result);                         
              console.log("Evento es: " + event);                                                                
            });       
      } 
      catch(err){
      console.log("Error is :" + err);
      }                     
  }
```

Which will give you the value you want:

```
CreateInspection(function(error, result) {
  if(error) {
    // Handle the error
  } else {
    // Process result
  }
});
```